# How to get the Website URL with the Analytics Data Export API?

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-api-java-client

is the website URL exposed by Analytics APIs ?

I can see the address in Analytics's own Account page
( such as https://www.google.com/analytics/settings/?pli=1#scid=XXXXX ) but I can't find it in the feed.

Am I missing something ?

Comment: Can you be more specific?  What do you mean by website URL?  When I use the page you reference it lists out all of my GA profiles.  There are GA Feeds which can query this information if that is your question.

Comment: In that page the URL of each website is shown. In the form of "http://example.com UA-9999999-1". I want to get that "example.com". I know Analytics has feeds, but the documentation doesn't contain any reference about how to get the website url.

Comment: ga:hostname dimension. http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/gdata/gdataReferenceDimensionsMetrics.html#ga:hostname

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [Google Analytics Management API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/)

Call the this API to enumerate your profiles:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/management/accounts/{ACCOUNT_ID}/webproperties/{WEB_PROPERTY}/profiles
```

It has a `websiteUrl` property for your site's URL, and a `defaultPage` property for your default page.

If you don't have the ACCOUNT_ID or WEB_PROPERTY, you can call:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/management/accounts
```

and once you extract your ACCOUNT_ID call the following to enumerate web properties:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/management/accounts/{ACCOUNT_ID}/webproperties
```